# JSR 352 Step Partitioning - Partition Restart Manually

Tags: java, batch-processing, websphere-liberty, jsr352

Is it possible to

1. Monitor the thread/threads of each partition
2. Restart them manually/programatically when they fail.

From what I have read, I understand that the batch framework handles it for us. However in case I want to do it on my own. How can I do it?

I am using IBM's implementation of JSR 352 on Webshpere Liberty.

Comment: So you want to be able to restart individual partitions of a certain step within a single job execution without restarting the overall job?

Comment: yes, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch framework does handle some of this for you.  It records the final status (e.g. **COMPLETED** or **FAILED**) for each partition and on restart of the job it will restart only those partitions which **FAILED** (by default).

But you only get to directly operate on the job.  So in general, you would restart a job with a **FAILED** partition by waiting until all other partitions had finished (**COMPLETED** or **FAILED**), then restarting the job, at which point the **FAILED** partitions would re-execute.

So it's designed to allow as much of the current execution as possible to complete, instead of failing-fast.

If what you were really looking for is to just restart each partition as soon as possible without waiting for all partitions to finish and the job to complete, you might want to look at the ***retry*** function in batch.

E.g. to rollback and retry on **SQLTransactionRollbackException** you can do this declaratively in XML via:

```
        <chunk retry-limit="3">
          <reader ref="...">
          ...
          <retryable-exception-classes>
            <include class="java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException"/>
          </retryable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
```

Does any of this fit well into your use case?  If not, would be interested to hear why not.

Comment: thank you! so if a partition has failed, if i wait for the job to complete and restart it only the partitions that have failed will run?

The usecase is that if a certain partition failed and it is due to some problem with the data(duplicate records etc), i dont want the partition to keep retrying on its own. What i want is to fix the data and just run that partition. So now as far as i understand  i will let the job fail and when it restarts only the failed partitions will run.  


Also what if i want to run the complete JOB again and not just the failed partitions?

Comment: So it sounds like a plain old job restart is what you want, and it sounds like **retry** might NOT be what you're looking for in fact.

Comment: Maybe you could you separate out your question about how to "run the complete JOB again" into a new question?     Might be hard to fit the answer into a comment, and it is easier for others to follow as a separate question.

Comment: i did [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779383/jsr-352-restarting-a-job) Thank you for your answers! i am very new to batch processing and JSR352 . So this is of great help.

Comment: Sure, please accept/upvote this answer and I'll take a look.