# JSR 352 Restarting a job?

Tags: java, batch-file, jsr352

When a job is restarted, only the failed partitions are run again. How do i run a successfully completed job again?

Is there a difference between submitting a job again and restarting the job?

i am using IBM's implementation of JSR 352 on Websphere Liberty.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: yes it did! i cant upvote your answer yet since i dont have enough reputation. But Thank You so much :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help, only mentioned the upvote on the other question since you were new to the site.  (I think you can still accept the answer though).

Comment: did you find how to maintain checkpoint in custom writer? am looking for some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Batch is designed so that when you restart a job instance, execution continues where you left off (in the previous failed or stopped execution).

So typically this means two things:

1. Within the job, you begin at the previously-failing step (or the step at which the job was stopped).
2. Within the step, you begin by positioning the input cursor using the checkpoint values kept by the batch container.

So if on the initial execution you completed *step1* then failed at *step2* at record #4123, and are checkpointing every 100 records, then on a restart you'd typically begin executing at *step2* at record #4100.

In some cases it's necessary to execute *step1* on the restart as well, before executing *step2* where the job had previously failed, and there is an option to get this behavior as well.

It is typical to submit/start a job repeatedly, often on a schedule.

In the terms of the batch specification, a new **JobInstance** is created each time a job is started.   At this time the initial **JobExecution** for this **JobInstance** is created.   If the execution does not run to completion, the instance may be restarted, at which time a second **JobExecution** is created for this **JobInstance**.

So a restart uses the checkpoints and execution history of the previous **JobExecution** while the start begins with a clean slate.

Comment: do we have any reverence for this

Comment: IBM has this [this document](http://www.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/5cb5ed706d254a8186256c71006d2e0a/c4f6acba4bd06f248525810d0075b8a7/$FILE/WP102706_WLB_JSR352.002.pdf/WP102706_WLB_JSR352.pdf) as part of [Techdoc WP102706](http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP102706).  Go to pg. 29 **Restarting a failed job**.    Also see [Techdoc WP102544](http://www-03.ibm.com/support/techdocs/atsmastr.nsf/WebIndex/WP102544) for other topics.